# Distributions in the context of geo-spatial data

Tags: spatial, pandas

I have geo spatial data with lat, lon of user activity. I have divided this data into geohashes with precision 6. For each geohash, how do I measure the distribution of points within them?

How do we think of distributions in the context of geo-spatial datasets? I am interested in measuring whether the spatial-distribution is uniform, Normal or some other type.

Which methods can be appropriate?

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a list of latitude and longitude values
lats = [-33.866667, -33.866667, -33.866667]
lons = [151.200000, 151.200000, 151.200000]

# Create a list of geohashes for each latitude and longitude value
geohashes = ['drt3w742y22w', 'drt3w742y22w', 'drt3w742y22w']

# Create a Pandas DataFrame with the latitude, longitude, and geohash values
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': lats, 'lon': lons, 'geohash': geohashes})
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I would like to add that [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) and [folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) are quite useful above just using pandas.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  **You** need to decide *what properties* of the distributions you are interested in.  Without such guidance, too many different and potentially conflicting answers are possible.  Please tell us what kind of data you have and what properties are of interest.

Comment: Is the above only a minimal example, or do you only have three data points?

Comment: @Galen It is a minimal example.